# How to save POST DATA in django?

Tags: python, django

Here is an example having:
**form with three fields i.e**

```
from django import forms
from models import Article

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title','body','thumbnail')
```

**view**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from uploadfiles.models import Article
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from forms import ArticleForm
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def create (request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/all')
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()
    args= {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('create_article.html', args)
```

**models**

```
from django.db import models
from time import time
def get_upload_file_name(request):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" %(str(time()).replace('.','-'))


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_ul}}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="create"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

MY QUESTIONS ARE:

1)What is Meta class, why we use this?

2)What this line means `args.update(csrf(request))`?

3)As in forms page redirects to `/create` .. as this can be any page! so how to save posted data now. as this returns the submitted data to html page.

*My question can be so basic or simple but these are the things that are not clear to me and for that reason i am posting this here! and it can be duplicate so if you don't like it please don't mark negatively.:)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
**Metaclass** is a 'thing' that creates classes.

You define classes in order to create objects, right?

But we learned that Python classes are objects.

Well, metaclasses are what create these objects. They are the classes' classes, you can picture them this way:

```
MyClass = MetaClass()
MyObject = MyClass()
```

You've seen that type lets you do something like this:

```
MyClass = type('MyClass', (), {})
```

It's because the function type is in fact a metaclass. type is the metaclass Python uses to create all classes behind the scenes.

Now you wonder why the heck is it written in lowercase, and not Type?

Well, I guess it's a matter of consistency with str, the class that creates strings objects, and int the class that creates integer objects. type is just the class that creates class objects.

for more help see this [MetaClasses](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/metaclasses/)

---

2)
Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)

A Cross-site request forgery hole is when a malicious site can cause a visitor's browser to make a request to your server that causes a change on the server. The server thinks that because the request comes with the user's cookies, the user wanted to submit that form.

Depending on which forms on your site are vulnerable, an attacker might be able to do the following to your victims:

- Log the victim out of your site. (On some sites, "Log out" is a link
  rather than a button!)
- Post a comment on your site using the victim's login.
- Transfer funds to another user's account.

To PREVENT this we use this `update(csrf(request))`

for more information see this [ABOUT CSRF](http://www.squarefree.com/securitytips/web-developers.html#CSRF) and this [CSRF django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/)

---

3)
`/create` is a action of your present controller if you see your controller page there you can see this create function in that function you'll get your POST data

Answer (score 1):

1) Meta = class metadata. This is where you define the different metadata elements of the model

2) CSRF = this is the token that prevents cross-site attacks. It is a hidden field/attribute that is added to your request to make sure someone cannot hack your site

3) The submitted data goes to the view and there your can save your data. Or I misunderstood your question....